# (openFileOutput) Necesito poder elegir el directorio (AndroidStudio)

Tags: java, android-studio

necesito poder elegir la direccion del archivo que se guarde cuando uno usa openFileOutput) en android studio idealmente en la external storage.... la idea es que se elija una carpeta para guardar varios archivos, necesito que la carpeta la pueda ver solo conectando el usb, gracias de antemano...

para crear la carpeta uso:

````
        File c12 = new File(getFilesDir(), "DatosMMR");
        c12.mkdirs()```




y para generar el archivo uso (solo necesito generarlo no leerlo):

```fos = openFileOutput(String.valueOf(n), MODE_PRIVATE);```
````

Comment: ¿Cual es el directorio que necesitas ? recuerda que no puedes escribir directamente en el directorio de almacenamiento interno directamente, pero si en el externo

Comment: Idealmente el de descargas o en verdad cualquiera que no necesite root para verlo